# Lock table order when pasting

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm a Windows Access newbie. However, I have to make some changes to our database at work.

I've created a new list of records with Excel, sorted as follows:

```
101A
102A
102.01A
102.02A
102.03A
103A
103.01A
...
```

When I copy & paste it in my access table, MS Access 2007 keeps my custom order until I restart the program. When I reopen it, the table gets sorted this way:

```
101A
102.01A
102.02A
102.03A
102A
103.01A
103A
...
```

How can I avoid this? Is there a way to "lock" my custom order when pasting from Excel to Access?

These records are being shown in a dropdown menu. but I'm not able to "code" in Access, I just have to change these table records by pasting them in the exact order I've established in my Excel table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database doesn't work like an Excel sheet.

If you select rows from a table (either opening the table directly, or using it as row source for a dropdown box), the rows are always returned in a certain **order**.

If you don't specify the order (`ORDER BY ...` clause), the primary key determines the order. In your case, this data column is probably the primary key.

And since `.` is sorted before letters (see Ascii table), you get the result you see.

To avoid that, you would need an additional column, e.g. "Sortnumber", where you can define the sorting you want, and use in a `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I solved creating an ID column and setting it as primary in the `ORDER BY ..`. clause. Thanks.